# Complete case analysis, multiple imputation, or instrumental variable analysis?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, panel-data, data-imputation

I ran a small study where all participants attended a psychological intervention, and completed measures at pre, post, and follow-up. Approx. 40 participants took part, of which approx. 5 did not complete the follow-up measures.

I suspect the data is missing at random (i.e. participants forgot there was a follow-up, didn't check emails, etc) but don't want to rule out the possibility that there was something about the intervention itself that meant they didn't finish.

Rather than risk introducing bias and further reducing a small sample by using complete case analysis, would it be appropriate to use something like multiple imputation, or instrumental variable analysis?

I'm not overly familiar with these approaches - any guidance on which might be 'best', or alternatives?

Many thanks!

Comment: What analytical method are you using?  (e.g. multilevel model? GEE?)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against complete case analysis. As you seem to know, this could result in bias and will certainly result in reduced statistical power.

With 5 out of 40 subjects lost to followup, the missingness proportion is rather modest and I would suggest multiple imputation, especially if the data are missing at random, but you can also run sensitivity analysis for MNAR.

I'm not sure why you think an instrumental variable approach would help. IV analysis is typically used to control for confounding.

You seem to have a repeated measures design, so you will also need to control for the non-independence of observations within subjects. A mixed effects model (with suitable covariance structure) or generalised estimating equations could be considered.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look into mixed effects models and GEE; I've previously used a repeated measures ANOVA for similar work.

I'm also undertaking another longitudinal study, but comparing variations of the intervention: three time points, two conditions, and similar numbers of participants and drop-out rate in each condition. 

Would these approaches (MI, followed by mixed effects model, for example) be suitable for that also?

Comment: Yes, I would have thought so.